# Identifying element's id in a chrome extension using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

So i am building an extension that copies some pre made answers to your clipboard. I have a problem with using the event listeners I need to make a logic to differ between answers. I need the events listener to recognize the ID of the button you are clicking.
Here's my html

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Retiros</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <button id="link">Clearing</button>
        <button id="bank">Invalid account</button>  
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var otra = document.getElementById('link');

    otra.addEventListener('click', function() {
        copyToClipboard();
    });
});

const copyToClipboard = str => {
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = 'Hola chicos, el retiro se encuentra rechazado por clearing';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
};
```

I need the var otra to identify the id without specifying it, I tried using event.srcelement.id inside () but didn't work.

Any help would be useful, sorry for my bad english and also my bad code skills

Answer (score 1):

Loop over collection of buttons and add a listener to each one. Then inside the handler `this` is the element the event occurred on

```js
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content button')).forEach(function(el) {

  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('id=', this.id);
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <button id="link">Clearing</button>
    <button id="bank">Invalid account</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In any modern browser you can directly use `document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content button').forEach`

Comment: @IvánNokonoko no support for it in IE

Comment: That's why I said **modern** :)